# Is there a more generic way of declaring this array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm currently learning Ruby and I saw this declaration:

```
 the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However, I feel there is a smarter way to declare this array with a pre-existing function. I'm wondering if there's a term for this particular array with the contents ascending by 1 as its index ascends by 1.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a range.

```
the_count = [*1..5]
```

...or...

```
the_count = (1..5).to_a
```

...or...

```
the_count = *(1..5)
```

(thanks to [Meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar).)

Comment: Why is the `*` required in the first declaration?

Comment: @stanigator It's the [splat operator](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation w/ the link.

Comment: Ironically, I've never had to use a splat with a `range`. If I need a `range` it's probably going to be used as an enumerator.